# C language — Fermat's theory validator not working properly

Tags: c, memory, cygwin, nested-loops

I have everything working properly.
code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int quadtest(unsigned long long int a, unsigned long long int b, unsigned long long int c,     unsigned int n)
{
    if ((pow(a,n)+pow(b,n))==pow(c,n))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

main()
{
unsigned long long int a;
unsigned long long int b;
unsigned long long int c;
unsigned int n;

n=3;
for(n; n<50; n++)
{

//printf("\nn=%u",n);
    for(c=2; c<500; c++)
    {

        printf("\ntrying now c=%llu and n=%u",c,n);     
        for(b=2; b<500; b++)
        {
            for(a=2; a<500; a++)
            {
                quadtest(a,b,c,n);
                if (quadtest(a,b,c,n)==1)
                {   
                    printf("\n|||||||||||||||||||||||WORKS|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||");
                    break;
                }
                //printf("\na=%llu, n=%u b=%llu c=%llu",a,n,b,c);   

            }
        if (quadtest(a,b,c,n)==1)
        break;}

        if (quadtest(a,b,c,n)==1)
        break;
    }
    if (quadtest(a,b,c,n)==1)
    break;
}       
if (quadtest(a,b,c,n)==1)
printf("\nthe correct values are a=%llu,b=%llu,c=%llu,n=%u",a,b,c,n);
else
printf("\nfermats theory is correct");
}
```

From my stance, I coded everything correctly, (I only used the ranges 50 and 500 so I could actually run it on my computer without it literally taking a day).

So I compiled the program in Cygwin (which I' required to use) and it took about 15 minutes or so then stopped at "the correct values are a=381,b=2,c=381,n=7" which is clearly incorrect.  I'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix this.  I think it has something to do with memory, yet still I'm not sure what a fix is for it.

Comment: thats what i thought, i wasnt sure what to make my ranges to to fix this.  i was thinking to change b<500 to pow(b,n) is less then a number, but i wasnt sure what that number is.

Comment: @Alex The problem is `pow()` operates on floating-point numbers which are inexact. Implement your own power function using repeated multiplication and it will work.

Comment: @Alex With `unsigned long long`, you get overflow pretty soon, apart from the problem of the limited precision of floating point values. If you want to run a correct brute-force, you need bignums.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing with doubles (`pow()` returns double),
 it is better to compare them by using an `EPSILON` as follows.
You create a "small" double (ex. `double EPSILON = 0.001`)
and compare to doubles by calculating the difference between the two variables.

```
double a,b;
if(abs(a - b)) < EPSILON){
     /* your code here..
}
```

Its important to use the `abs()` function so you don't have to
worry if `(a > b) || (b < a)`

In order to get better results you can choose a smaller `EPSILON`.

write this:

```
if ((pow(a, n) + pow(b, n) - pow(c, n)) < EPSILON) {
    return 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

pow() takes double arguments and returns a double. double has limited precision (usually it uses 64 bits). There exists a double x such that (x + 1.0) == x. This is essentially what you're running into, since 381**7 is a very large integer.

To do this sort of calculation correctly, you need a way to do exact math on large integers. What you need is generally known as a "bignum" library. GMP is one such, you might want to check it out.

Comment: can i just change the limit to something else for a,b,c?  the teacher never taught bignum so im pretty sure he didnt want us to use that for this.  will making my own power function work?

Comment: If this is homework, is it possible that the teacher simply wants you to understand that types in C have limited precision, and why the obvious solution fails? In C, unless you roll your own bignum library, you'll run into problems with writing your own power function. If you stick to integer types, you'll get a different kind of problem -- an overflow. There's no n such that (n+1) == n, but there's an n such that (n+1) < n.

Comment: Well its homework but its not to understand data types have limited precision.  im not really sure what the bignum is unfortunately.

Comment: Do you need to do this in C? Some other languages such as Python have built-in support for representing large integers exactly. As long as you're working in a language such as C that doesn't, you need additional code to work with such integers. That's what you'd find in a bignum (big number) library. I think it's unlikely that your teacher wants you to use one of those if they haven't mentioned these issues at all, but it's worth being aware of.

Comment: Sorry, didn't note the first sentence of your comment. If you chose these ranges yourself, then it's possible that your teacher simply didn't expect you to work with numbers this large. Be aware in particular that an exponent of 50 is large. You won't be able to represent 3**50 in an unsigned long long.